# ios: Please give me the smtp mail coding according to attached pic

Tags: ios, smtp, sendmail

[image]

Please can anyone help me. how to create connect to server for mail sending.

ans is http://iphonesdksnippets.com/post/2009/04/15/Send-email-with-attachments-on-iPhone.aspx

Comment: Please give more context. What do you want to achieve, what have you done and what is your problem. Please update your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it using: [**skpsmtpmessage**](http://code.google.com/p/skpsmtpmessage/)

This is a nice article [**Sending emails from Cocoa**](http://vafer.org/blog/20080604120118/), please check it also.

Comment: note that the skkpsmtpmessage does not have active download currently.

Answer (score 1):

You need a middle server to receive REST call and process it in any way you want. Any iOs networking interface might be used for this purpose, there's a lot of samples how to create a simple request.

Answer (score 0):

Please give more context of your question. Do you want to achieve it solely by IOS? Or you don't mind to write a bit of server code?

If you are OK to write a bit of server code, you can try Google App Engine API for sending email ( using googgle account ). You have 3 choices of language : Java, Phyton or Go.

Full documentation is located at [Google App Engine](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail) website.